# how can regexp sub replace preceding zeros of stream of digits while keeping the last zero of a stream of all zeros (postgres)

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I want to normalize a hex number that's stored in a varchar col of a PG table by eliminating preceding zeros (I need to compare vals that may be represented differently).  Easy enough.  But I also want to preserve the last zero if the stream of digits is all zeros.  Example...

```
create table foo (col1 varchar);
insert into foo (col1) values ('''h000123abc'),('''h123abc'),('''h0123abc'),('''h000000000');
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'''h',''),'^0+','') from foo;
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 123abc
 123abc
 123abc

(4 rows)
```

As you can see, the actual hex val has a "'h" prefix which I had to get rid of.
I want to preserve a single 0 in the case where the val is 0.  I want that last row to be '0'.

I'll file this one under both PG and regexp and regexp-replace because I expect the straight regexp soln would map OK to the SQL func regexp_replace.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression to perform different replacements depending on whether the value is all 0 or not.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '^''h0+$') THEN '0'
        ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '^''h0*', '')
    END AS new_col1
FROM foo
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3XqHM4ygxqBFx3kcJwLr9s/0)

There's also no need to use separate calls to `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove the `'h` and the leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regexp which matches a leading `'h` with `0`'s up to at least one character before end of line (which will prevent removing all `0`s in `'h0000`) and replacing the match with an empty string:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '^''h0*(?=.+$)', '')
FROM foo
```

Output for your sample data:

| regexp_replace |
| --- |
| 123abc |
| 123abc |
| 123abc |
| 0 |

Demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99kzeJfXFUneiuDh3iuXyc/1)

Answer (score 1):

You might use a capture group capturing the last character and use that in the replacement.

```
^''h0*(.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hxOkda/1)

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '^''h0*(.)', '\1')
```

Output

```
123abc
123abc
123abc
0
```